# Siemens CSTA with C#

Tags: c#, connection

I need a quickstart for the connect ... maybe someone with experience on C# and how to make CSTA Link ? I just find one example but in Perl on [Perl CSTA Example](http://search.cpan.org/~timos/Net-CSTAv3-Client-0.06/lib/Net/CSTAv3/Client.pm), but I still don't know hot to do on C#.
Thanks a lot!
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Siemens exposes `CSTA API's`. You can use those. There is a `CSTADLL` which is a collection of software for the `Microsoft .NET platform` that allows you to perform `ACSE` and `CSTA` operations for any of the three `CSTA` phases.

There are two namespaces you should have a look at: `Com.Objsys.Csta.Common` and `Com.Objsys.Csta.Devices` - depending on what exactly you are about to do.